# Question about Statistics and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes

Hi I want to know I can predict an outcome for an even with naive bayes if i have 3 outcomes rather than 2. E.g yes,no and maybe rather than just yes and no?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142505/how-to-use-naive-bayes-for-multi-class-problems

Comment: Perfect, thank you!